# Regular expression - Hive / Impala - Capture word between 2 char

Tags: regex, hive, impala

I would like to capture and extract, in Hive/Impala using the `regexp_extract` function, all the words between two characters (`/` and `-`) and also the first word from the beginning of the text up to the character `-`.

I have a string like this:
`key1-value1/key2-value2/key3-value3/keyN-valueN`
I want the function to extract:
`key1`
`key2`
`key3`
`keyN`

with variable number of occurrences of the key-value pair.
Eg:
`abc-bca/abc.s-13:13:13/any-x/keyn-1`

and I want the function to extract me:
`abc`
`abc.s`
`any`
`keyn`

I'm using the following regex, but it only works if I have 3 keys:
`^(.+)-(?:.+)/(.+)-(?:.+)/(.+)-(?:.$)`
How can I extend it to n (variable) keys?

Thanks

Comment: Would [`(?:(.+?)-(?:.+?)(?:\/|\s|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/to5sAh/1/) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

if it supports lookbehind

```
(?<=^|\/)[^\-]*
```

or if it supports perl notation `\K`

```
(?:^|\/)\K[^\-]*
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CseTPH/1/)

- `^|\/` : matches start of line or `/`
- `[^\-]` : matches any character except `-`

Comment: They are not working. Hive / Impala uses the Go language notation. [Regex Tester - Golang](https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html)

Comment: in this case it's not possible to do it just with one regular expression, the closest `(?:^|/).*?-`, includes `/` and `-`

Answer (score 0):

```
select explode( split(regexp_replace('key1-value1/key2-value2/key3-value3/keyN-valueN','(?<=^|/)(.*?\\-)',''),'/')) as col1
```

- regexp_replace, replaces all the characters from start of the line or from slash to hyphen(-).
- split function the converts the left of the string based on '/'.
- explode function converts array elements into rows.